# clear modal bootstrap form in angular

Tags: forms, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

what is the best way to clear bootstrap modal form data without using jquery?

I could use this, but I would like to know the angular way of clearing modal form data.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
      $('#Username').val("");
 });
```

***Edit:***

I have multiple elements on the form. I found out the easiest way is to create a service to reset the object and updates the ng-models on the form.

To reset the form object, call the shared service to reset:  `mySharedService.resetObj();` To clear the form in controller:

```
$scope.myObj = mySharedService.getObj(); 
$scope.myForm={}; 
$scope.myForm.myData = angular.copy($scope.myObj);
```

all the elements is under the 'myData' item.

Comment: I tried creating a service with a function to reset the form, copy the empty object to the ng-model form in the controller, and trigger this from a div that wraps the href to the modal link. That worked for me.
To reset the form object, call the shared service to reset:
  `mySharedService.resetObj();`
To clear the form in controller:
  

    $scope.myObj = mySharedService.getObj();
    $scope.myForm={};
    $scope.myForm.myData = angular.copy($scope.myObj);
all the elements is under the 'myData' item.
Then I call this function from the div that wraps the href to the modal link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-bind` to set the value of whatever inside the `<div class="modal-body">` equal to a `$scope` variable, then change the `$scope` variable on whatever action you want, most likely on the `cancel` event, like so:

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.yourVariable = "";
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

the binding is like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div ng-bind="yourVariable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have multiple elements on the form. I found out the easiest way is to create a service to reset the object and updates the ng-models on the form.